Unmounting drives and running from RAM?
In the "cheap" VPS world, you can normally only install an image from a limited range of ISOs. The one I'm looking at at the moment lets you select between 2 or 3 versions of Alma, Rocky, Debian, or Ubuntu.
This is a problem if you have a custom ISO that you want to run on a VPS (I have a custom 22.04).
There is a potential workaround, however. In this workaround, you switch or reboot to a RAM disk, with the (virtualised) drive unmounted. It's then straightforward to download a new disk image, write it to the drive, and then reboot to your new OS.
The first bit is difficult. If you install Ubuntu at a VPS you probably only get grub options for a kernel and recovery mode, so there's no 'live' option.
Any ideas? I'm thinking that overlayroot with tmpfs might possibly handle this, but I can't see that it would survive unmounting the drive.
